# Can i delay an style object to appear for certain time using setTimeout in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i want to make the style to like delay for certain time before it appear in react, to put more simply like, when i hit the toggle which will change the height of my element (openNavbar) after a certain of given time.

JSX :

```
const [ navbarIsToggle, setNavbarIsToggle ] = useState(false); // Store the navbar toggle state

const openNavbar = {
    height: navbarIsToggle ? '100vh' : '0'
}
```

HTMX :

```
<nav className="navbar-body wrapper" style={{ ...openNavbar }}>

</nav>
```

Comment: You could use a CSS transition with a duration of `0ms` and a delay. But I'd do it through a class (like `wrapper-expanded`) instead of inline styles. That way you have more control about the look and you can manage the transitions for expand/collapse seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is sparse on real code but I will assume your styling is working in the instantaneous case. If you have a toggle button, use `setTimeout` to delay setting the state.

I will assume a delay in milliseconds

```
const delayInMs = 1000;
```

```
<button onClick={() => setTimeout(() => setNavbarIsToggle(v => !v), delayInMs)}>Toggle Me</button>
```